# How to output of structured stream without truncation in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to output structured stream result to console:

```
.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.format("console") \
.start()
```

output table looks like that:

```
+--------------------+--------+--------+
|            column#1|column#2|column#3|
+--------------------+--------+--------+
|08/25/2022 00:00:...|abcde...|12345...|
+--------------------+--------+--------+
```

how can I output the whole content without truncation? expected result is as using `show(truncate=False)`:

```
+--------------------+--------+--------+
|            column#1|column#2|column#3|
+--------------------+--------+--------+
|08/25/2022  00:00:00|abcdefgh|12345678|
+--------------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Try:

.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option('truncate', 'false').start()

Comment: @过过招 Yes, it shows the output as I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As specified in [documentation for the Console Sink](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks), set option `truncate` to `False`, e.g.:

```py
query = (
    df
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", False)  # <-- this
    .start()
)
```

You can also use the `options` method to set multiple options at the same time:

```py
query = (
    df
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .options(
        truncate=False,
        numRows=10,
    )
    .start()
)
```